# Could not load file or assembly Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework in MVC5

Tags: oracle, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I want add Oracle EntityFrameWork to MVC5, in the webconfig i set 
`<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>`.

[But when run project but it throw ex In method ApplicationDbContext like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7N8u.png)

Comment: Try installing & referencing `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` assembly, e.g. in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/. If it still doesn't solve the issue, also install VC++ Redistributable depending on server OS version & platform (x86/x64). Note that the platform version of your app build must be match with installed redist package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 or later with .NET Framework 4.5 or later.
- Oracle Database 12c or later.
- Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) 12c Release 3 (12.1.0.2.1) or later from OTN. The ODAC download includes Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio and ODP.NET
- Files required for this tutorial.
- Using NuGet to Install and Configure Oracle Data Provider for .NET tutorial.(install: **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework** from Nuget).

refer: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/2015/entityframework_linq_modelfirst/Entity%20Framework%20LINQ%20and%20Model%20First.html#overview